# Stuck after logout. /dev/sda4: clean, 188688/5472256 files, 1364950/21881600 blocks

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning

```
/dev/sda4: clean, 188688/5472256 files, 1364950/21881600 blocks
```

I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.4.2 after having the same problem a few hours ago and when I logged out it freezed at this screen again. (The underscore is still blinking)

It's like this for half an hour. I've tried to search for the solution but nothing helped. Alt + f2 (or is it f1?) works, so I can use the terminal.

The only ways this doesn't show is with recovery mode and nomodeset (all though it freezes in the Ubuntu loading screen).

I installed it along side windows 10. In another partition of course.

Comment: Can you get to root access in Recovery Mode and show us the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`? Please begin comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema hey, thanks for trying to help. I uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Debian instead. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wish that we could have communicated before you went to Debian, as I suspect the fix would have been very easy with Ubuntu. Cheers, Al.